# Android - CPU usage and Battery drain

Tags: android, performance, cpu-usage

I have some navigation application, I want to know how different sample rate of sensors in my app impacts on battery drain.
I make several tests using: `adb shell dumpsys cpuinfo` command. 
Results(accelerometer and gyro):

0Hz - cpu usage is: 17%

15Hz - cpu usage is: 20%

100Hz - cpu usage is: 23%

How i can know from CPU usage, how much battery life is reduced?(for example if i use my app for 1 hour)

Comment: Most Android phones will tell you how much (relatively) each app is using the battery. This can be found under Settings > Battery > MyApplication

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know voltage/amperes levels for each clock speed value your system is configured, this information may be obtained from your device sometimes (if you have root access), or from datasheet.

Next you need to know how much time CPU spent in each state, for that information check `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpuN/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state`.
Related question: [Android read CPU time in states for multicore devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37422846/android-read-cpu-time-in-states-for-multicore-devices)

Then multiply difference between idle and running power consumption, add 
idle level and the value will be more or less exact amount of power it spent to run your device for some time. Comparing this value with values obtained when program wasn't run and run with different parameters will allow to make guesses about battery life changes.

But keep in mind that power consumption depends on many other factors, not just CPU speed and utilization. For example, sensors also consume power (some sensors - a significant amount), and display with radios usually waste by far most of battery charge in any real-life situations.